# Click table elements of table inside iframe with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The content I am trying to click on is inside table of a table in an IFrame. I can switch to the IFrame, but cannot click on the link test that goes to another page.

```
List<WebElement> click1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html//body//table[7]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/font/a"));
    int clicks = click1.size();
    System.out.println(clicks);
```

This prints out 1 but when I clicked this using the following code, it gave me error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed
```

Command duration or timeout: 10.53 seconds

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    StringBuilder locator = new StringBuilder();
    locator.append("document.getElementByXpath('//html//body//table[7]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/font/a').click();");
    executor.executeScript(locator.toString());
```

Comment: A google search told me that your error (waiting for evaluate.js load failed) is because you are on FF 22 or later.  FirefoxDriver has to catch up after each firefox release.  Downgrading to 21 may fix your problem.

Comment: @MrTi So I tried with IE 8 with the same code but cannot click on the elements inside the IFrame.

Comment: If it is throwing the same error, then you need to post your HTML.  It's really hard to debug selector problems without seeing what you are selecting.

Comment: @MrTi   This is an extract from tbody of table inside table.<tbody> <tr> <tr valign="top"> <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF"> <tr valign="top"> <td nowrap=""></td> <td nowrap="" colspan="8"> <a target="_self" href="/sample/OZ.NSF/Web%20View%20RRP!OpenView&Start=1&Count=1000&Expa‌​nd=2.1#2.1"> <font size="1" face="Verdana" color="#6260a1"> <script> <a href="wwv.sample.com.au/sample/OZ.NSF/…; </font> </td> <td></td> </tr> <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#EFEFEF">

Comment: I got to click first row by using partical link text, but this text is dynamic. So I will try to loop table and click dynamic test.